# Cron Job daily schedule

Tags: server, cron

I need a cron job. It should run be every day on Monday till Thursday, starting at 16:30, executing every 5 minutes till 03:30 AM next day. On Friday it will start at 16:30 executing every 5 minutes till Monday 03:30 AM. Thank you very much!

Comment: When exactly do you want to start? Midnight or 23:05? ANd are you sure the export will end in 5 minutes?

Comment: I want it to start at 23:05 every weekday, run every 5 minutes until next day at 11:00AM.

Comment: Do you want to run at 23:05 on Sunday for Monday run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment you need two records like this:

This cover:

> Need to run every weekday from Monday till Thursday, starting at
>   23:05, exporting every 5 minutes till 11:00 AM next day

```
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 23 * * 1-4 command
*/5 0-11 * * 2-5 command
```

This cover:

> On Friday start to run at 23:05 until Monday 11:00 AM

```
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 23 * * 5 command

*/5 * * * 6,7 command
*/5 0-11 * * 1 command
```

And when we optimize the cron records we will get something like:

```
*/5 0-11 * * 1-5 command
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 23 * * 1-5 command
*/5 * * * 6,7 command
```

**EDIT1:**
As per question change you need:

> Monday till Thursday, starting at 16:30, executing every 5 minutes
>   till 03:30 AM next day

```
30,35,40,45,50,55 16 * * 1,2,3,4 command
*/5 17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * *  1,2,3,4,5 command
*/5 0,1,2 * * 2,3,4,5 command
0,5,10,15,20,25 3 * * 2,3,4,5 command
```

> On Friday it will start at 16:30 executing every 5 minutes till Monday
>   03:30 AM

```
30,35,40,45,50,55 16 * * 5 command
*/5 * * * 6,7 command
*/5 0,1,2 * * 1 command
0,5,10,15,20,25 3 * * 1 command
```

And to "optimize" the cron records

```
30,35,40,45,50,55 16 * * 1-5 command
*/5 0,1,2 * * 1,2,3,4,5 command
0,5,10,15,20,25 3 * * 1,2,3,4,5 command
*/5 17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * *  1,2,3,4,5 command
*/5 * * * 6,7 command
```

Comment: you can reduce the second line as `5-55/5 23 * * 1-5`

Comment: @kvantour, I usually use old UNIX definitions and was not aware of this option :)

Comment: Thank you all. In the module I'm using I can use both lines so I used */5 0-11 * * 1-5;5-55/5 23 * * 1-5. In regards weekend, I also need to start on Friday 23:05 and end on Monday 11:00AM. Any idea?

Comment: @Daniel, do you want to run only during weekend. Please update your question (and check my edited answer)

Comment: Hey, OK, will explain.  Need to run every weekday from Monday till Thursday, starting at 23:05, exporting every 5 minutes till 11:00 AM next day. On Friday start to run at 23:05 until Monday 11:00 AM. I know it may be confusing..

Comment: @Daniel, please check my updated answer, based on your last comment

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay! I need a correction please and it will make it easier. It should run be every day on Monday till Friday, starting at 16:30, executing every 5 minutes till 03:00 AM next day. On Friday it will start at 16:30 executing every 5 minutes till Monday 03:00 AM. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Daniel, please update your question. Or ask new one

Comment: @RomeoNinov thank you very much. What do you mean about the "optimize"?

Comment: @Daniel, by "optimize" I mean combine some records to minimize the number. If you check my edited answer you will see for 1st requirement are need 4 records, for 2nd also 4. But you can combine them and on the end have only 5 cron records :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank you very much, I'm trying it, as for now looks fine!!

Comment: @Daniel, in such case feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: I did :))). Thanks again, appreciated!

Comment: Hi @RomeoNinov, the cron is working all the week, for some reason it stopped working today Sunda at 00:00. Any idea?

Comment: @Daniel, no idea. Check in cron log if something happen

Comment: @RomeoNinov can you try to review again the records you provided to see of some any of them is interfering with others and avoiding to work on Sunday?

Comment: @daniel, the last record run cron jobs every 5 minutes, Saturday and Sunday. `*/5 * * * 6,7 command`

Comment: @RomeoNinov correct, when I check it on https://crontab.guru it says "Non standard! May not work with every cron.". Actually every cron I checking on weekend it shows this warning. Any idea?

Comment: @Daniel, have no idea. If */5 do not work you can try `0,5,10,15,....55`